# An error occurred while creating datasets: Dataset could not be created

Tags: charts, dataset, dashboard, apache-superset, kylin

I have a running Kylin Cluster in Kubernetes and Superset in Kubernets also.

1. Kylin is already configured with a built cube "kylin_sales_cube"
2. Superset is already configured with Kylin driver and the connection is established.

While trying to create a dataset from a Kylin table I get the following error message:

> An error occurred while creating datasets: Dataset could not be created.

On the other hand, I am able to run a query on the same table, but without dataset, I cannot use charts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a lack of implementation of a method in kylinpy (or somehere else) but until someone solves it, I suggest everyone who has this problem to implement the has_table method in sqla_dialect.py from kylinpy plugin. You will find it in kylinpy/sqla_dialect.py, and the method is:

[image]

You should change that return to the next line:

```
    return table_name in self.get_table_names(connection, schema)
```

And everything will be back to normal.